# How to keep the text align of each other

Tags: html, css

This is the site i'm working on. http://elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/

The text at the top with the icons/images (call us, visit our showroom, Watch our video), I can't seem to keep the text align of each other.

So the text should be within the same line of each other. Everytime I put space in the image/icon moves further to the left.

This is the code -

```
<div class="topSection">
    <div class="logo">
       <a href="<?php echo $siteURL;?>/index.php"><img src="<?php echo $siteURL;?>/images/eg_logo_new.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>
<br>
<p style="float:right;"> Call Us: 01924 724848</p>
<img style="float:right;" src="images/mobile.png"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br><br>


<p style="float:right;">&nbsp; &nbsp;Visit Our Showroom</p>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/''/elegant+curtains+and+blinds/@53.6967136,-1.7011525,12z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x487960059226814f:0x337f355d1975d87c!2m2!1d-1.631113!2d53.696734"><img style="float:right;" src="images/images.png" height="30px" width="30px;"/></a><br><br>

<p style="float:right;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Watch Our Video</p>
<a href="https://youtu.be/DAasK7kF2DQ"><img style="float:right;" src="images/video.png" height="30px" width="30px;"/></a>


    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex` for modern browsers, it's mush easier to work with. Here is a possible solution for your problem (click on `Run code snippet` to see the result):

```css
.topSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.info img {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topSection">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="http://www.elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/index.php"><img src="http://www.elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/images/eg_logo_new.png" alt="Logo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="info">
      <img src="http://elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/images/mobile.png" height="30px" width="30px;" />
      <p>Call Us: 01924 724848</p>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
      <img src="http://elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/images/images.png" height="30px" width="30px;">
      <p>Visit Our Showroom</p>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
      <img src="http://elegantcurtainsandblinds.co.uk/images/video.png" height="30px" width="30px;">
      <p>Watch Our Video</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[More info on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank You brother. Works brilliant.

Comment: Glad it helped.